# SSIS Check If First Of the Month run with variable A if not run with variable B

Tags: sql, variables, ssis

I have a ssis package that needs to run daily. But it needs to make a check first: If it's the first of the month, run the package passing variable A; if it's not the first of the month then pass variable B.

Comment: I have provided an answer to your question. Can you please confirm whether your question is answered?

Answer (score 2):

Best solution is to run the package daily from SQL Agent. Within the package itself, include a variable with an expression that checks to see what the current day of the month it is running for (i.e., use GETDATE()), parse the date for the day and check for 1. If 1 then VariableValueA else VariableValueB. So, your expression looks like this:

```
DAY(GETDATE()) == 1 ? "VariableA" : "VariableB"
```

Note: make sure the data type of the variable matches the expression output. As you see in the example above, the output is string so the variable needs to be of data type String. If your variable values are integer then the variable data type needs to be Int32 (or Int64 if 64-bit), etc.

See my answer here for how expressions work.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53598832/4630376